# Bootstrap Cols empty Space 700-900 Width ~ Why?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with bootstrap atm. and cant figure out why my col elements create wierd empty spaces. It should be a simple issue but I am searching for an hour now and still cant find the solution.

Website with the problem: http://www.concierge-service-dortmund.de/

Its happens on all browsers at width 700-900 ~

Thats the problem screenshot: http://puu.sh/lAogM/bbaef8e510.jpg

I`ve tried some solutions which I found here but they didnt worked and actually the issues there were a bit more complex.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a float issue. The "Gardinenwäsche" div needs a clear: left; to repair the DOM.

Comment: thanks adding: clear: left to "Gardinenwäsche" and "Einkaufsservice" Divs on width 700 - 900 fixed the probelm

Comment: tbh this is not a perfect solution, it is not dynamic. It only works for a particular case. To make it dynamic he will have to clear after every second in sm and after every fourth in lg.

Comment: With media queries, he can clear: left elements with a nth-child(2n+2) or something like that, it's gonna be dynamic so :)

Answer (score 0):

The row which separates the blocks has "margin-left: -15px;" and "margin-right: -15px;" and this is causing the boxes jump underneath.

To fix this, add a class to the div with rows (there are 4 on the site) to remove the margin.

```
<div class="row noMargin">
```

CSS:

```
.noMargin {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap columns allow nesting! Since you're using 1 2 or 4 columns you can change your markup to the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

OffTopic: Bootstrap is "mobile first" remember to add a `col-xs-*` to every column no matter if it will be 100% anyways, you might prevent some clearing issues with that.